# Is there a reason user principals don't persist in tomcat sessions?

Tags: session, tomcat, jdbcrealm

Why does a user principal not persist in a tomcat session when using a realm? Is there a way to configure the valve realm or session to persist it? Are there security issues with this technique?

The reason I ask is that every time I redeploy our application (a few times a day at least), it logs everyone out of the realm. That's not terrible now, but we need a solution for production.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. When I stop tomcat SESSION.ser file is written to the file system. When I start it and refresh the browser window, SESSION.ser is read and deleted. Principal information is lost in `FormAuthenticator.doAuthenticate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are not shared between web applications so when you deploy a new version of your application every user will get a new session and therefore have to log in again.

One option would be to use parallel deployment. That lets multiple versions of an application run in parallel. If you have version 001 deployed then all users will use version 001. When version 002 is deployed, users with sesison for version 001 will continue to use it. New users without a valid session will be directed to version 002. A user that was using version 001 whose session expires will be directed to version 002 when they next make a request.

If you undeploy an old versions, any users still with sessions will be logged out and moved to the latest version.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have used the term deploy. Forgive my lack of detail and knowledge in Tomcat terminology. When I make a few minor changes in my project through eclipse and test it, the sessions persist, but the principals do not. Clearly they are not serializable, but I was curious as to why.

Comment: @Zuill I do not understand. The sessions can't be said to persist if everyone is logged out.

Comment: @EJP When the server resets, it seems to keep session variables for a particular user (the user still has an unexpired session cookie that "persists" on the server across the refresh. However, the realm authenticator does not remember the user and asks them to log-in again. Thus I end up with existing session variables but no user principals. Why not just store the principals in the sessions across server "refreshes" (or whatever you would call it)? Is it a security risk? I guess there could be a way for people to modify them which is a security risk?